# how to call different controller's method with the same route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

Suppose I have some `services`( ex:mouse, keyboard, monitor ) under a `category`( computer accessories ). For `category` the route is `http://url.com/category`. Now I want for `services` route will be `http://url.com/category/services/{{service-name (ex:mouse/keyboard)}}`.

Also called two different functions for the routes. Called `category()` function for route `http://url.com/category` and `services()` function for route `http://url.com/category/services/{{service-name (ex:mouse/keyboard)}}`

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order. Handle the route `http://url.com/category/services/{{service-name}}` first and then `http://url.com/category`. routes/web.php is first come first serve. So set up the order correctly.

Or change `http://url.com/category` to the more canonical `http://url.com/categories`